# error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I am getting this linker error.

> **mfcs80.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj)**

Please tell me the correct way of eliminating this bug. I read solution on microsoft support site about this bug but it didnt helped much.

I am using VS 2005 with Platform SDK

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you read the linker error thoroughly, and apply some knowledge, you may get there yourself:

The linker links a number of compiled objects and libraries together to get a binary.

Each object/library describes

- what symbols it expects to be present in other objects
- what symbols it defines

If two objects define the same symbol, you get exactly this linker error.  In your case, both mfcs80.lib and MSVCRT.lib define the _DllMain@12 symbol.

Getting rid of the error:

1. find out which of both libraries you actually need
2. find out how to tell the linker not to use the other one (using e.g. the [tip from James Hopkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrtlib#343413))

Comment: Missing detail - some libraries define weak linkages, defining the correct library inclusion order would have mfc used first and msvcrt second and so silently drop the weak linkage

Comment: That detail has cost me hours of astonishment and misery (silently linked in an imported library's `main`).  Weak linkages may have their use, though.

Answer (score 54):

I had the same error message, but none of the answers here solved it for me.
So if you Encounter that Problem when creating a DLL Project that uses MFC, it can be resolved by entering the following line:

`extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; }`

to the cpp file where `DllMain` is defined. Then your own `DllMain` implementation is used, rather than the one from dllmain.obj.

> When we try to use MFC library, we surely will include afx.h directly
> or indirectly, then MFC(afx.h) tell the linker to find the symbol of
> __afxForceUSRDLL and put that object which contains __afxForceUSRDLL into the program, so linker searches and puts dllmodule.obj into our
> program, because __afxForceUSRDLL is defined in dllmodule.cpp.
>
> That’s the common scenario. When we want to use our own DllMain in a
> mfc dll project, linker complains that there are two DllMain, one in
> our code, one in Dllmodule.obj.
>
> So we need to tell the linker to add our dllmain.obj for
> __afxForceUSRDLL. So we need to define __afxForceUSRDLL in our own cpp file where our own DllMain is defined, then the linker will ignore
> mfc’s dllmodule.obj and see only one DllMain and never complains.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d78aa6b-1e87-4c01-a4a7-691335b7351a/how-to-build-mfc-application-dll-in-visual-c-2010

Comment: Worked for me, I had AfxWin.h included and slightly different library causing the problem:
uafxcwd.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined

Comment: Worked for me with VS2008 and a DLL where I'd caused the link error by  using MFC collections, specifically CMapStringToString.

Comment: I removed `//AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());` 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9070135/1641556

Comment: For code that must compile as 32 bit and 64 bit use this
    #ifdef _X86_
    extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }
    #else
    extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; }
    #endif

Comment: @JonDrnek
This should be:
#ifdef _WIN64 
extern "C" { int __afxForceUSRDLL; }
#else 
extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }
#endif

Comment: These options also doesn't work for me...                  i am now getting error: mfcs140.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in  xxxMyclassMain.obj

Comment: It's now 2023 and I am using VS 2019. The error I got had very little detail, just these two lines: 'LNK2005 _DllMain@12 already defined in dllmain.obj' and 'LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found'. I used Anurag's solution, but JonDrnek's may work as well. My starting point was a MS article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170, which doesn't say anything about this. C++ is a little too finicky sometimes. I'm trying to program, not understand all these switches to support an endless array of environs.

Answer (score 11):

If you're defining your own DllMain, in your project settings you need to set 'Use of MFC' in the 'Configuration Properties/General' to 'Use Standard Windows Libraries'.

You should do a clean rebuild after changing it.

Comment: I have a pure C, non-MFC DLL set to "Use Standard Windows Libraries," but the error still pops up.

Comment: I found that removing _WINDOWS from the preprocessor defines in Project Settings -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor got rid of the spurious reference to MSVCRTD.lib . I'm using VS2010.

Answer (score 9):

In my project I was able to solve this problem by adding mfcs80.lib and msvcrt.lib as additional dependencies in the project settings. The 'additional dependencies' can be found under Linker -> Input.

In the debug configuration that would have to be mfcs80d.lib and msvcrtd.lib respectively.

By the way, I am working with Visual Studio 2010, so in my case the MFC lib is called mfc100.lib.

I am not sure why this worked. It is not necessary to add these lib files as additional dependencies because I already set 'Use of MFC' to 'Use MFC in a shared dll'. I guess that by specifying these libraries as additional dependencies they are linked in a different order.

This solution is more or less the same as the one suggested on the Microsoft site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652, except I did not need to type anything in the 'Ignore specific default libraries' box.

Answer (score 8):

For me the direct cause was indeed a missing _afxForceUSRDLL symbol reference, but the indirect cause was a missing _USRDLL macro definition. It is defined by default by the VC wizard, but occasionally devs erase it erroneously.
[Here it is in more words](http://ofekshilon.com/2012/08/18/_dllmain12-already-defined/).

Comment: I had the opposite! I had a rogue _USRDLL in the preprocessor that should have been a _LIB. Doh!

Answer (score 5):

MSDN knowledge base ID Q148652.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Cause:
Visual C++ compiles the source files in alphabetical order, and passes the compiled object files to the linker in alphabetical order.
If the linker processes DLLDATAX.OBJ first, the source code references DllMain, which the linker loads from MSVCRTD.LIB(dllmain.obj).
The linker then processes an object file compiled from a C++ file that contains #include "stdafx.h", which references the symbol
__afxForceUSRDLL, which the linker loads from MFC42D.LIB(dllmodul.obj). This object module also contains an implementation for DllMain,
causing the conflict.

Answer (score 4):

I have a very similar problem. [mfcs110d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dllmain.obj)] and the solution was **add mfcs110d.lib to Additional Dependencies**

Comment: I am also getting same error:                                                              
mfcs140.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in msvcrt.lib(dll_dllmain_stub.obj)                                                                                                                        Tried by adding these libraries in 'Additioonal dependencies' but still it couldn't solve.. I am still getting same error.. I am building dll as final output not an exe..

Comment: Have a simple project sample to download?

Answer (score 4):

For all those who are experiencing this error in ATL projects (mostly when trying to add MFC support), here's the solution I found after days of frustration!

First of all, [this link](http://www.dziwior.org/WindowsProgramming/Link_fails_with_multiple_includes_of_DllMain.html) was more helpful to me than all the others. It pointed me into the right direction. The problem occurs, if the "generated files" (containing the proxy and stub code, just as the type guids) for some reason have been removed and readded to the project. This causes Visual Studio to add them in the wrong order!

Usually you first come up with the "ATL requires C++ compilation" error, but you may have fixed this by turning out the `Yc/Yu` (precompiled headers) setting for that file.

What you should do next is unloading your project and edit it. Search for the item groups that define the build and include order (`ClCompile` and `ClInclude`). Check their order and settings.

The compiles should appear in this order:

1. `dllmain.cpp` (with `CompileAsManaged` set to `false` and `PrecompiledHeader` left empty).
2. Library source (`MyLib.cpp`, containing `DllCanUnloadNow` and so on)
3. Proxy/Stub code (`MyLib_i.c`; with same settings as `dllmain.cpp`)
4. `stdafx.cpp` (with `PrecompiledHeader` set to `Create`)
5. All the other library source files (your actual libraries content)
6. `xdlldata.c` (with the same settings as `dllmain.cpp`)

The includes should then be ordered like this:

1. `dllmain.h`
2. `MyLib_i.h`
3. `Resource.h`
4. `stdafx.h`
5. `targetver.h`
6. ... (actual library headers)
7. `xdlldata.h`

Fixing the build order fixed my project and I was able to create a new clean build.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that this answer was immensely helpful; I did not know the linker was dependent on the build inclusion order in the project, but indeed, this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have personally got rid of this error this way: right-clicked project in the `Solution Explorer`, selected `Properties` from pop-up menu, clicked `Linker` tab and added `mfcs71ud.lib` into `Additional Dependencies`. If you're using Visual Studio 2005, it should be "80" instead of "71" and so on.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. [mfcs110d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dllmain.obj)] and the solution was **add mfcs110d.lib to Additional Dependencies**

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had a problem with the preprocessor directives. 
For some reason `_USRDLL` was defined, when it should not have been.

To check this, go to the menu  <kbd>Project</kbd> , select  <kbd>Project Properties</kbd> , then select the snippet  <kbd>Configuration Properties</kbd>  -->  <kbd>Preprocessor</kbd> .

The preprocessor directives will be found there.

Comment: This advice has to be slightly updated for Visual Studio 2107. Select your project in the Solution Explorer, right click and select Properties. Now go to C/C++>Preprocessor>Preprocessor definitions, and edit out _USRDLL

Comment: user1741137 - Is gennerally right, but instead of having to wait 86 years from know, the advice has been valid for about 4 years already  [snarky: 2017 not 2107] :)

Answer (score 3):

Declare the `mfc80ud.lib` and `mfcs80ud.lib` in the `Additional Dependancies` field in the `Project Properties -> Linker Tab -> Input of Visual Studio` to fix the issue.

Comment: Though somebody gave the same answer about a year earlier, this one is on top, so I'll leave my 5 cents here. It seems the msvcrt.dll imports dllmain only when it wasn't declared earlier. Adding the mfc*.dll to "Additional Dependencies" makes it being processed earlier and solves the issue. As somebody else mentioned /FORCE:MULTIPLE sliences the linker as well, yet in my case produced .dll was crashing in runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Just `#undef` the `_USRDLL` before including `afx.h`, or even better, edit your project configuration and remove the macro.

This is the usual configuration for a MFC extension DLL: [Build Settings for an MFC DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235516%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you include "Stdafx.h" at the top of each .cpp file.  I was getting the exact same error and had a single .cpp file that did not include this header at all.  Adding the #include solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found solution Here
[Visual Studio 2010 library linking order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765403/visual-studio-2010-library-linking-order)

this is: /FORCE:MULTIPLE 
in linker options

I had to mix ATL and MFC together , to use
[module(name = "mymodule")]; construction in MFC application together with "__hook" keyword

Answer (score 2):

I found this which helped me:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148652

Basically the linker order was incorrect. the CRT libs were getting linked before the MFC libs. Turns out, the MFC libs had to get linked FIRST, and then the CRT libs could be linked.

Yucko Microsoft!!

Answer (score 2):

There is a common theme running through some of the answers here.

Avishek Bose:-

> Declare the mfc80ud.lib and mfcs80ud.lib in the Additional
>   Dependancies field in the Project Properties -> Linker Tab -> Input of
>   Visual Studio to fix the issue.

vmb100:-

> I am working with Visual Studio 2010, so in my case the MFC lib is
>   called mfc100.lib.

joseAndresGomezTovar:-

> I have a very similar problem. [mfcs110d.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error
>   LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dllmain.obj)] and
>   the solution was add mfcs110d.lib to Additional Dependencies

So the general case seems to be to first find the name of the library to add ...

[image: Library name]

and then to add it ....

[image: Add Library to Dependencies]

Note that there seem to be some [prerequisites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/343413/3070485) and/or [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930430/3070485) solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This can also occur if your solution has multiple projects that export the same symbols. For example if you have sub-project that builds `foo.dll` with a `foo.def` file that exports `DoFoo` *and* a sub-project for `bar.dll` with a `bar.def` file that exports `DoFoo`, a collision will occur and this is the error you will see when you link.

Answer (score 0):

In case of migrating from old version of Visual Studio to new one, maybe this help:
got to project Properties => C/C++ => Preprocessor => preprocessor definitions

add *__afxForceUSRDLL* and done.

Also check if there was *_USRDLL* there, delete it and just add *__afxForceUSRDLL* .
this helped me