# _DllMain@12 already defined

Tags: dll, mfc

I try to build subproject ExplorerPlugin from mDNSResponder-107.6.tar.gz archive but
receive next link error:

> **uafxcwd.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined**

how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are using MFC.  It already has a DllMain entrypoint, required to initialize MFC properly.  Check this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148791) for recommended workarounds.  Hard to otherwise provide a better answer, you didn't provide a link and it looks to me like this is Apple code, very un-mfc-ish.

Answer (score 13):

I had exactly the same problem and this fixed it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19930430/625227

Enter this code in the .cpp file where your DLLMain function is

```
extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }
```