# calling functions inside DLLMAIN()

Tags: c++

im trying to create DLL file and im having problem running functions inside DLLMAIN().

i want to do somthing like this :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
INT APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved){

switch (ul_reason_for_call) {

case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    foo1();
    break;

case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    foo2()();
    break;

}
return true;
}


void foo1(){
 //code
 }

void foo2(){
 // code
}
```

but it does not work.
when I'm trying to build the file im getting

```
'foo1' identifier not found
'foo2' identifier not found
```

what I'm doing wrong here?

thanks!

Comment: This is C 101; it has nothing to do with Windows or DllMain. Functions need to be declared before you call them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you have not declared the functions. Put a

```
void foo1();
void foo2();
```

before yout DllMain and it will compile.

But be warned. [You should not do anything substantial in DllMain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140821-00/?p=183). Especially anything involving loading libraries directly or indirectly might result in deadlocks.

Comment: thanks. but now im getting  those errors : DllMain@12 already defined in Dll1.obj , one or more multiply defined symbols found. any idea what wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539238/dllmain12-already-defined