# trying to display UI in C++ DLL from VB6 causes assert at AfxGetResourceHandle

Tags: vb6, mfc

I have a legacy vb6 code that calls into c++ to display MFC dialog.
Calling AfxGetResourceHandle to load the dll's resource onto the memory causes debug assert.
Has anyone done this?

```
    HINSTANCE priorRes = AfxGetResourceHandle();

    if (m_MDCommonDll == NULL)
    {
        m_MDCommonDll = LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll");
    }

    AfxSetResourceHandle(m_MDCommonDll);
```

If this is not possible to do, is there a way to detect if the caller is from vb6 so that I can skip showing the UI?

Thanks

Comment: Is this an MFC extension dll or an MFC regular DLL?

Comment: Did you use AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062034/what-does-afx-manage-stateafxgetstaticmodulestate-do-exactly

Comment: thanks that fixed the issue. Do you know what is the difference between AfxSetResourceHandle and AFX_MANAGE_STATE are? From MSDN description, they sound pretty similar

Comment: resource handle is just one of the state that needs to be switched when entering a MFC regular DLL.

Answer (score 1):

AfxGetResourceHandle( ) can throw a debug assert if you mix release and debug build DLLs. Make sure your .exe and any .dlls it loads are all built as either release or debug.