# Not able to use string format in visual c++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I created a `Win 32 dynamic link library` project in `visual c++ 6.0`, whereas i wrote the following code and it showing some error at compile time.

```
for(i = 0; i < (int) len; i++)
{
 strTmp.Format("%C", m_Track1Buffer[i]);
 strASCII += strTmp;
}
```

When i am compiling the above code it shows me following error:

```
error C2228: left of '.Format' must have class/struct/union type
```

I have includes the following `header files` in my code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <String.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <winsock2.h> 
#include <windows.h>
```

Apart from that please tell me why i am not able to use `CString` in above project. I also included the `alstr.h`, but it didn't help me.

Comment: When you ask questions about a 15 year old compiler then you need to post better repro code.  Best guess is that you simply forgot to declare strTmp.

Comment: clearly you did not declare strTmp as the correct type -- but you didn't post that code, so we can't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you haven't got MFC support in your project.

Your best solution is to start again by making your project an MFC DLL to start with and copy your code in.

Failing that, you can add MFC support in Project settings > Link > General > `Use MFC in a static/shared library`.

Also required: In stdafx.h comment out `#include <windows.h>` and add

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
```

You're then faced with the problem that you have two `DllMain()` functions - one in your dll and one in the MFC internals. Comment out the one in your dll (though your requirements may be different. See further reading here: [error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRT.lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrt-lib))

If you're just doing this only for CString support then don't. Rather just use std::string instead.