# DLLMain() is not being executed after injection

Tags: c++, windows, dll-injection, dllmain

I have written a dll and injector in C++. The dll code is given below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <winsock.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "wsock32.lib")

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void UploadFile()
{
.....
}

INT APIENTRY DLLMain(HMODULE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch(fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0,"Process Attach","Info",MB_OK);
        UploadFile();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        MessageBox(0,"Thread Attach","Info",MB_OK);
        UploadFile();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

The dll uploads a particular file to the server. I am successfully able to inject the dll into "notepad.exe" using LoadLibrary() and CreateRemoteThread() but it is not being executed. Not even the dllmain() function. Dont know what is wrong.

Comment: The function should be called `DllMain` with lowercase L. (I guess I should make this into an answer.)

Comment: Doing things this complicated from DllMain is a free ticket to crash or deadlock. Read [MSDN remarks on DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) for reference. Why do you need injected DLL to upload a file?

Comment: This is the error I got after changing DLLMain() to DllMain()

error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dllmain.obj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Dirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035029/dirk) has already stated, the DLL entry point is named `DllMain()`, not `DLLMain()`. The signature for [`DllMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) is:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
    DWORD fdwReason,
    LPVOID lpvReserved
);
```

From [Best Practices for Creating DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx)
, you should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain():

> ...Call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized...

`MessageBox()` is implemented in `User32.dll` so this may be a possible cause of `DllMain()` appearing to not be invoked.

It is unwise to perform any time consuming tasks with `DllMain()` as it will prevent the application loading any other DLLs that is requires, as the loader lock is held when inside `DllMain()`. Instead, spawn a thread to perform any time consuming task. The linked document advises against using `CreateThread()` but only if synchronization is involved.

Comment: +1 and add [Some reasons not to do anything scary in your DllMain](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx) and [Another reason not to do anything scary in your DllMain: Inadvertent deadlock](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/28/63880.aspx)

Comment: The return type should also be `BOOL` although that probably doesn't really matter.

Comment: +1 IIRC since the application is already running if all dependencies of the injected DLL are already satisfied a good deal of those restrictions no longer apply and you're free to go bananas. That might apply only to process attach though depending on thread local initialization.

Comment: @Faheem, why would you consciously choose a conflicting signature for no benefit?

Comment: I will change it to `BOOL` but I am also getting this error !!!

`error LNK2005: _DllMain@12 already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(dllmain.obj)`

Comment: @Faheem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrt-lib .