# CUDA: error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in MSVCRT.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

When the `cuda_test.cu` file is not included in the project, the code runs fine.

When such a file is included, I receive the following error message

```
mfcs100u.lib(dllmodul.obj) : error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in MSVCRT.lib(dllmain.obj)
```

`cuda_test.c`u has the following header files, a global function and a wrapper.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>
```

So I am not sure what causes this problem.

After some research, it seems this problem is fairly common and has
[fixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrt-lib). But this starts giving trouble in a different part of the code. ("StdAfx.h" is included in all .cpp files, if this information is relevant).

It is a huge project written in C++ and I am trying to parallelize some parts of it.

Some help will be hugely appreciated. I can give extra details if needed.

Comment: Take a look at this post: [Compiling CUDA mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/498). In particular, the post scriptum part. It describes the _error LNK2005: DllMain already defined in MSVCRT.lib_ and a way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks. that helped. but ignoring `msvcrt.lib` completely was also giving error. what worked was ignoring both libraries `mfcs100u` and `msvcrt`, and adding them again as additional dependencies. ( change in order helps if I remember)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all parts of your app link against the same runtime.

In Solution Explorer, right click your `.cu` file and select Properties. Go to `CUDA C/C++ > Host` and make sure that `Runtime Library` is set to the same as for the rest of your project.

Comment: `CUDA C/C++ > Host ` was `<inherit from host>`. So that should be ok I guess