# Registering a DirectshowFilter links InprocServer32 registry entry to regsvr32.exe instead of host DLL, where did I go wrong?

Tags: com, visual-studio-2017, directshow

I have a DirectShow filter (**MonogramAAC encoder**) successfully compiling. It also registers successfully, however, when I try to instantiate the filter in GrapheditPlus, it shows a `CO_E_ERRORINDLL`.  After inspecting the filter properties under GraphEditPlus,  the filter was actually linked to **RegSvr32.exe** instead of the actual host DLL!

Here's the evidence:

[image]

[image]

I'm sure the .def file in the linker is correct, I also tested that it IS being considered by the compiler and it is correctly pointing to the filter DLL.

A little bakground info:

I couldn't get the original project to compile under Visual Studio 2017 after automated conversion.  *(I couldn't resolve strange MFC and runtime library linker errors between the Monogram filter and the `libaac.lib` library, that I'm also able to compile successfully)*.

Finally I decided to recreate a brand-new VS2017 Project mimicking the original one and got it to compile and register (with the only warning being the mismatch between the Project name and the output library), but obviously I missed something important while recreating the project.

**Any pointers?**

Comment: I manually redirected the InprocServer32 registry entry to the correct .ax file and the filter worked (well, the property page is not showing up so I'm missing something there), but I am still baffled as to why this is happening!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find the reason for this unexpected behavior [in this old post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.directx.video/CYQ7ZETkYbk).

> RegSvr32 just calls the DllRegisterServer entry point in your code. 
>   What  gets written to the registry is entirely up to your filter. **If
>   you are using the standard baseclass call to AMovieDllRegisterServer2
>   as  your DllRegisterServer, I would suspect that something went wrong
>   in setting  up g_hInst, which should have been done by the call
>   DllEntryPoint in your  DllMain**.
>
> …
>
> The DllMain is not being called, so **g_hInst stays 0 and
>   GetModuleFileNameA(...) returns the name of the currently executing
>   program instead of my filter.**

The filter is using MFC (dynamically linked), and its `DllMain()` version is not calling the `DllEntryPoint()` function.  I had to override the MFC DllMain() by adding `extern "C" { int _afxForceUSRDLL; }` as described in [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343368/error-lnk2005-dllmain12-already-defined-in-msvcrt-lib/19930430) and call `DllEntryPoint()` myself to fix the registration problem.  (I also found a missing #define was the reason for the property page not showing up).